# Not able to receive push notification to iOS devices when using Amazon SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/sns-send-push-notifications-ios.html). I am able to register device tokens in the [application](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home) endpoint list successfully. The message has been published to registered tokens. The delivery status says `success` (status code 200) in cloud watch console. But the device isn't able to receive notifications in iOS devices. What could be the reason?

**Note**: I have enabled notification settings in devices and ios project.

Comment: Did you upload p12 certificate with correct format in SNS console? How did you generate p12 with private key or with out private key?

Comment: Certificates. We were stuck for a while before trying to regenerate certificates from the ground up. The mistake we made was that we created certificates from an already used certificate request. We made a brand new one just for the purpose of SNS.

Comment: Hi Karthikeyan,
i have generated p12 file by exporting my certificate from keychain access under my certificate section. The p12 file generated with private key.

Comment: Hi Crazyrems, I have generated new certificate request and used this. Still it is not working.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin SDK or iOS SDK? Can you follow this documentation for iOS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html?

Comment: See [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310259/firebase-notification-to-device-with-fcm-token-says-sent-but-not-received#comment77585055_45310259)

Answer (score 0):

Double check the Message format setting. I ran into this same issue and the Cloud Watch console was reporting the message as sent even though I never received the message on my iOS devices. For me, messages were not received when the message format was set to JSON. Messages were received when the message format was set to Raw.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem on the mobile network as I have received the push notifications after changing my network
Try changing your internet network used in your mobile and test again